# Add Cell to "Favorites" TableView from DetailView

Tags: ios, objective-c, uitableview, uiviewcontroller, uibutton

I have an existing UITableView that lists a number of cafes in the area. The data for each cafe is being pulled from a MySQL database. When a user clicks on a cafe (cell), it brings a user to a detail view. Currently, users can "Favorite" a cafe by clicking on the star image in each cell (this adds the favorited cell to FavoritesTableView). However, I want users to be able to add a cafe to the FavoritesTableView from the DetailView as well (in other words, "favorite" a cafe from the DetailView). Does anyone know how I would implement this?

Right now, I have the star button in place in my **DetailView.m** (cafe details):

```
- (IBAction)buttonpressed:(UIButton *)fave {
    if (!checked) {
        [checkedButton setImage:[UIImage imageNamed:@"checked.png"] forState:UIControlStateNormal];
        checked = YES;

    }

    else if (checked) {
        [checkedButton setImage:[UIImage imageNamed:@"unchecked.png"] forState:UIControlStateNormal];
        checked = NO;
    }

}
```

**ViewController.m** (cafes tableview)

```
- (UITableViewCell *)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView cellForRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath
{

    static NSString *strainTableIdentifier = @"StrainTableCell";

    StrainTableCell *cell = (StrainTableCell *)[tableView dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier:strainTableIdentifier];
    if (cell == nil)


    cell = [[StrainTableCell alloc] initWithStyle:UITableViewCellStyleDefault reuseIdentifier:strainTableIdentifier];

    cell.accessoryType = UITableViewCellAccessoryDisclosureIndicator;
    cell.selectionStyle = UITableViewCellSelectionStyleBlue;



    NSArray *nib = [[NSBundle mainBundle] loadNibNamed:@"StrainTableCell" owner:self options:nil];
    cell = [nib objectAtIndex:0];

    if (tableView == self.searchDisplayController.searchResultsTableView) {
        NSLog(@"Using the search results");

        cell.titleLabel.text = [[searchResults objectAtIndex:indexPath.row] objectForKey:@"Title"];
        cell.descriptionLabel.text = [[searchResults objectAtIndex:indexPath.row] objectForKey:@"Description"];
        cell.ratingLabel.text = [[searchResults objectAtIndex:indexPath.row] objectForKey:@"Rating"];
        cell.ailmentLabel.text = [[searchResults objectAtIndex:indexPath.row] objectForKey:@"Ailment"];
        cell.actionLabel.text = [[searchResults objectAtIndex:indexPath.row] objectForKey:@"Action"];
        cell.ingestLabel.text = [[searchResults objectAtIndex:indexPath.row] objectForKey:@"Ingestion"];

        NSLog(@"%@", searchResults);



    } else {
        NSLog(@"Using the FULL LIST!!");
        cell.titleLabel.text = [[Strains objectAtIndex:indexPath.row] objectForKey:@"Title"];
        cell.descriptionLabel.text = [[Strains objectAtIndex:indexPath.row] objectForKey:@"Description"];
        cell.ratingLabel.text = [[Strains objectAtIndex:indexPath.row] objectForKey:@"Rating"];
        cell.ailmentLabel.text = [[Strains objectAtIndex:indexPath.row] objectForKey:@"Ailment"];
        cell.actionLabel.text = [[Strains objectAtIndex:indexPath.row] objectForKey:@"Action"];
        cell.ingestLabel.text = [[Strains objectAtIndex:indexPath.row] objectForKey:@"Ingestion"];

    }


    NSMutableDictionary *item = [Strains objectAtIndex:indexPath.row];
    cell.textLabel.text = [item objectForKey:@"text"];

    [item setObject:cell forKey:@"StrainTableCell"];
    BOOL checked = [[item objectForKey:@"checked"] boolValue];

    NSLog(@"%i",checked);
    UIImage *image = (checked) ? [UIImage   imageNamed:@"checked.png"] : [UIImage imageNamed:@"unchecked.png"];
    UIButton *button = [UIButton buttonWithType:UIButtonTypeCustom];
    CGRect frame = CGRectMake(0.0, 0.0, image.size.width, image.size.height);
    button.frame = frame;
    [button setBackgroundImage:image forState:UIControlStateNormal];
    [button addTarget:self action:@selector(checkButtonTapped:event:)  forControlEvents:UIControlEventTouchUpInside];
    button.backgroundColor = [UIColor clearColor];
    cell.accessoryView = button;

    return cell;


}


- (void)checkButtonTapped:(id)sender event:(id)event
{
    NSLog(@"made it here and event is %@",event);

    NSSet *touches = [event allTouches];
    UITouch *touch = [touches anyObject];
    CGPoint currentTouchPosition = [touch locationInView:self.StrainTableView];
    NSIndexPath *  indexPath ;
    indexPath =  [self.StrainTableView indexPathForRowAtPoint: currentTouchPosition];
    NSLog(@"indexpath is below");
    NSLog(@"%@",indexPath);
    if (indexPath != Nil)
    {

        NSMutableDictionary *item = [Strains objectAtIndex:indexPath.row];
        BOOL isItChecked =  [[item objectForKey:@"checked"] boolValue];

NSMutableArray *quickArray = [[NSMutableArray alloc] initWithArray:Strains];
        [quickArray replaceObjectAtIndex:indexPath.row withObject:item];


        [item setObject:[NSNumber numberWithBool:!isItChecked] forKey:@"checked"];
        Strains = [quickArray copy];

 [StrainTableView reloadData];

    }

}

    - (void)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView didSelectRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath {



        StrainDetailViewController *detailViewController = [[StrainDetailViewController alloc] initWithNibName:@"StrainDetailViewController" bundle:nil]; if ([searchResults count]) {

            detailViewController.title = [[searchResults objectAtIndex:indexPath.row] objectForKey:@"Title"];
            detailViewController.strainDetail = [searchResults objectAtIndex:indexPath.row];

        } else {

            detailViewController.title = [[Strains objectAtIndex:indexPath.row] objectForKey:@"Title"];
            detailViewController.strainDetail = [Strains objectAtIndex:indexPath.row];
            NSLog(@"%@", Strains);
        }


        [self.navigationController pushViewController:detailViewController animated:YES];



        // Release any retained subviews of the main view.
        // e.g. self.myOutlet = nil;
    }


    - (void)viewWillAppear:(BOOL)animated
    {
        [super viewWillAppear:animated];

        if ([[NSUserDefaults standardUserDefaults] objectForKey:@"strains"] != Nil) {


            NSData *dataSave = [[NSUserDefaults standardUserDefaults] objectForKey:@"strains"];
            Strains =  [NSKeyedUnarchiver unarchiveObjectWithData:dataSave];
        }


        if (favoritesArray == Nil) {
             favoritesArray = [[NSMutableSet alloc] init];   
        }



        if ([[NSUserDefaults standardUserDefaults] objectForKey:@"favorites"] != Nil) {


            NSData *dataSave = [[NSUserDefaults standardUserDefaults] objectForKey:@"favorites"];
            favoritesArray =  [NSKeyedUnarchiver unarchiveObjectWithData:dataSave];
        }
```

I'm just not sure what sort of code I would add to this in order to make the "Checked" button add the selected cell from UITableView to FavoritesTableView.

Hope this made sense. Any ideas?

Comment: Does your table view get deallocated when you navigate to the details view, or does your details view get pushed on top of the table view?  Does the list of cafes in your table view have a favorite flag (or something similar)?

Comment: Hi Jeff! The details view gets pushed on top of the table view (I believe). And yes, the list of cafes currently has a favorite flag (a star). I've updated my code above so you can see how the existing "favourite" function works. Apologies for the code overload lol.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

From a maintainability stand point, the approach I generally take might not be the best.  However, from an implementation stand point, it's very easy.  I pass a reference to my object (in your case, the object for the table view that was selected) to the details view.  From the details view, I can update that object by switching the flag.  Since this object is the same object as the table view, updating it will also update the table view (you may have to redraw the table view cell).  Last, I update the database from the details view.

## Edit

So in your code, it would look like this.

```
- (void)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView didSelectRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath {

    StrainDetailViewController *detailViewController = [[StrainDetailViewController alloc] initWithNibName:@"StrainDetailViewController" bundle:nil]; if ([searchResults count]) {

        detailViewController.title = [[searchResults objectAtIndex:indexPath.row] objectForKey:@"Title"];
        //YOU'RE ALREADY DOING IT :)
        detailViewController.strainDetail = [searchResults objectAtIndex:indexPath.row];

    } else {

        detailViewController.title = [[Strains objectAtIndex:indexPath.row] objectForKey:@"Title"];
        //YOU'RE ALREADY DOING IT :)
        detailViewController.strainDetail = [Strains objectAtIndex:indexPath.row];
        NSLog(@"%@", Strains);
    }

    [self.navigationController pushViewController:detailViewController animated:YES];
}
```

You're already sending a reference to the details view!  This makes things easy.  In your details view, whenever someone favorites a strain, set the favorite flag for the strainDetail object.  This will also update the strainDetail object in the table view.  It works like this because you're passing a reference (also referred to as a pointer) to the detail view.  In other words, both of your strainDetail objects, aren't objects but pointers to a memory address.  If you update either strainDetail, the the memory address for both strainDetail gets changed.  Not the strainDetail pointer itself.  Here's an link for further explanation  https://softwareengineering.stackexchange.com/questions/17898/whats-a-nice-explanation-for-pointers

So your Details view handler will look something like this

```
- (IBAction)buttonpressed:(UIButton *)fave {
    if (!checked) {
        [checkedButton setImage:[UIImage imageNamed:@"checked.png"] forState:UIControlStateNormal];
        checked = YES;

    }

    else if (checked) {
        [checkedButton setImage:[UIImage imageNamed:@"unchecked.png"] forState:UIControlStateNormal];
        checked = NO;
    }

    //updates in both the detail view and the table view
    BOOL isItChecked =  [[self.strainDetail objectForKey:@"checked"] boolValue];
    [self.strainDetail setObject:[NSNumber numberWithBool:checked] forKey:@"checked"];
}
```

I also suggest creating a Strain class to hold all of your strain data.  Working with dictionaries is not fun, is error prone, and takes forever to figure out what keys you need.

Comment: Ok, so pardon my ignorance (I'm still kind of learning/grasping the lingo, lol), but what would this look like in my code? Help :)

Comment: I updated my post.  Also, I don't think you need to do replace the entire object and array when something changes in your table view.  You should be able to modify the object and not need all the other stuff.

Answer (score 0):

You can save "favorite" state in a global variable/singleton and retrieve it when needed.

This way, even if your table view is deallocated, you won't lose its cells' state.